# Use LINQ on stored procedure results without enumerating the stored procedure results first.

Tags: c#, .net, linq, sql-server-2008

I have a stored procedure that creates and executes a dynamic query. I'd like to be able to use the results of that stored procedure as an IQueryable that has not yet been executed.

IE

```
context.StoredProcedure(parameter1, parameter2)
        .Where(i => i.StatusID != 2)
        .OrderBy(j => j.Policy)
        .Skip(recordsToSkip)
        .Take(pageSize).ToList();
```

Is this possible? I do not want the procedure to return a list of results, and then to perform the pagination.

Comment: Why not put the pagination details in the stored proc and pass them through?

Comment: I'm not sure it's possible in pure TSQL (you'd probably have to fetch SP results to temporary table and query that table). Looks like your SP should really be a View.

Comment: We already have a function that takes a IQueryable and will return an IQueryable that includes the paging and sorting algorithms. I'd like to use that so it is more centralized.

Comment: In that case I would go with what @MarcinJuraszek said. Wrap a view around it, so that you can have your `IQueryable` hit the DB with a nice query.

Comment: Hm ok. I'm not what it means to wrap a stored procedure in a view but I guess that's a different question.

Answer (score 0):

Use Table Value Functions instead of stored procedures. It returns IQueryable, so you can use linq-to-sql in queries.